# How to monitor/statistics about SQL operations in Oracle, such as Executor, Rows and SQL Text

Tags: sql, oracle, monitor

How to monitor/statistics SQL operations in the Orace database? Taking the SELECT operation as an example, it can monitor the specific SQL statement of the operation, the user who executes the statement, the number of database rows found by the statement.

In MySql, there is a default library performance_schema that can implement this function. Is there a similar library in Oracle?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tdppt/monitoring-real-time-database-operations.html#GUID-CE183666-D270-41B1-8410-8CE968168127

Comment: The SQL Monitoring feature allows you to see in real time what an execution plan is doing ... but it requires the Enterprise Edition of Oracle PLUS the Diagnostic & Tuning packs.

Comment: Thanks! But I have another question. Can all SQL Execution be monitored and not just the monitored SQL Execution? The current requirement is mainly to count the number of data rows obtained by users from the oracle database rather than SQL tuning.

Comment: Please, describe what do you want to achieve?