# In oracle database, how to query/count the number of rows of data obtained by a user from the database in a certain period of time？

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, monitoring

Our need is to know how many pieces of data the user has obtained from the database, and charge by the number of pieces of data.
This is similar to database monitoring, but database monitoring is mostly for SQL tuning, but we are doing a statistic on all SQL operations.
In MySQL, we implement this function through performance_schema, which records each SQL executed by the user. The record contains the ROWS_SENT field, which describes the number of rows of data returned by the statement to the client. Is there a similar function in Oracle?

Comment: There is not a similar function in Oracle.

Comment: Billing user by the number of rows produced by a query is a very bad idea. select * from dual returns 1 row, as does, for example, select count(*) from any_table. The first SQL costs virtually nothing, while the second may cost lots of I/O, ...

Comment: You have already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822716/how-to-monitor-statistics-about-sql-operations-in-oracle-such-as-executor-rows). Why do you ask it again? You may [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822716/how-to-monitor-statistics-about-sql-operations-in-oracle-such-as-executor-rows) and add more details of the original issue to it to make it answerable.

Comment: The easiest way to break this metric is to return a dataset as a single JSON object or a collection type. You may check [DBA_HIST_STATS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_HIST_SYSSTAT.html#GUID-C94C6E6D-3FB0-4A81-A350-A1F312CDFEBB) to obtain retrospective data and [Statistics description](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/statistics-descriptions-2.html#GUID-2FBC1B7E-9123-41DD-8178-96176260A639) to decode that data. Additionally, container database may provide more easy way for measurement.